# When you click on one of the boxes, for it to change color and stay that color

Tags: html, css

I have 3 boxes inside my section3holdingbox and I want it so if a user clicks on one of the boxes for it to change to a darker shade of red and let it stay like that until he clicks another box. also for the first box to be pre selected has a darker red. heres my code so far, i couldn't get it to work

```
HTML: 

<div class="section3HoldingBox">

<div class="section3Box1">
        <a href="#section3"><div class="section3BoxTitleBasic">Basic</div> <!-- end of section3BoxTitleBasic -->
</div></a><!-- end of section3Box1 -->

<div class="section3Box2">
        <div class="section3BoxTitleComingSoon">Professional</div> <!-- end of section3BoxTitles -->
</div> <!-- end of section3Box2 -->

<div class="section3Box3">
        <div class="section3BoxTitleComingSoon">Deluxe</div> <!-- end of section3BoxTitles -->
</div> <!-- end of section3Box3 --> 


</div> <!-- end of section3HoldingBox -->
```

CSS:

```
.section3HoldingBox {

    width: 1350px;
    height: 210px;
    margin: 25px auto 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: blue 2px solid;
}

.section3HoldingBox a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.section3HoldingBox a:active {

}

.section3Box1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    border: 2.2px rgba(231, 76, 60, .38) solid;
    background-color: rgba(231, 76, 60, .2);
    float: left;

    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;

}

.section3Box2 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 219px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    border: 2.2px rgba(231, 76, 60, .38) solid;
    background-color: rgba(231, 76, 60, .12);



    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.section3Box3 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    border: 2.2px rgba(231, 76, 60, .38) solid;
    background-color: rgba(231, 76, 60, .12);
    float: right;

    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.section3Box1:hover, .section3Box2:hover, .section3Box3:hover {
    border: 2.2px rgba(231, 76, 60, .83) solid;
    background-color: rgba(231, 76, 60, .17)
}
```

Comment: Could we please get the HTML as well?

Comment: There! i just updated

Comment: Can't you add a new css role like "active" and then add a javascript event that will add the "active" class to the div you recently clicked?

Comment: Yeahs that probably a good idea also one more thing, Only the text is clickable for the <A> tag, is there anyways i make the whole box clickable instead?

Comment: Wait scratch that, I put my a tag before the "basic" word not before the actual div tag! I got it working now!

Comment: And for the hover part, when i hover over the text, it rotates, can i make it so when i hover over the actual box it will rotate ?

Comment: Nice, yeah just put the transition into the hover role!

Comment: Its a custom class though i made .section3BoxTitleBasic .... can i implement it in the .section3Box1:hover {} tag ?

Comment: The last css role you have in your code applies every time you will hover a sectionbox so basically, yeah it should only be to add the transform into that role!

Answer (score 0):

The CSS `:target` pseudo-class is an efficient solution for this kind of problem.

Once you have set up your `:target` pseudo-class style rules, you'll also need to add a short one-line javascript, so that the first box is pre-selected as soon as the window loads.

```js
function initialise() {
 window.location.hash = 'box1';
}


window.onload = initialise();
```

```css
.section3HoldingBox {
    width: 1350px;
    height: 210px;
    margin: 25px auto 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: blue 2px solid;
}

.section3HoldingBox a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.section3Box1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    border: 2.2px rgba(231, 76, 60, .38) solid;
    background-color: rgba(231, 76, 60, .2);
    float: left;

    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.section3Box2 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 219px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    border: 2.2px rgba(231, 76, 60, .38) solid;
    background-color: rgba(231, 76, 60, .12);

    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.section3Box3 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    border: 2.2px rgba(231, 76, 60, .38) solid;
    background-color: rgba(231, 76, 60, .12);
    float: right;

    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.section3Box1:hover, .section3Box2:hover, .section3Box3:hover {
    border: 2.2px rgba(231, 76, 60, .83) solid;
    background-color: rgba(231, 76, 60, .17)
}

div[id^=box] a {
display: block;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

div[id^=box]:target {
    border: 2.2px rgba(63, 0, 0, 1) solid;
    background-color: rgba(127, 0, 0, 1)
}

div[id^=box]:target a {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)
}
```

```html
<div class="section3HoldingBox">

<div class="section3Box1" id="box1">
<a href="#box1">
<div class="section3BoxTitleBasic">Basic</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="section3Box2" id="box2">
<a href="#box2">
<div class="section3BoxTitleComingSoon">Professional</div>
</a>
</div>

<div class="section3Box3" id="box3">
<a href="#box3">
<div class="section3BoxTitleComingSoon">Deluxe</div>
</a>
</div>

</div>
```